# Debugging both .net and stored procedure in VS 2008 together

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2008, debugging, stored-procedures

I know we can debug the stored procedures in Visual Studio but is it possible to debug the .NET code and Stored Procedures together? I mean if my .NET code calls a stored procedure, whether my debugger will still continue with the stored procedure step by step.